# How to download files efficiently with Python?

Tags: python, download

I want to download files.

I used asyncio but it had no response for a long time when downloading files. Furthermore, it has problems when the server certificate is invalid.

Here is my code:

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
async def get_file(url, folder, session):
    filename = folder.strip('\\') + '\\' + str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':', '_') + '.pdf'
    async with session.get(url, headers = headers) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            f = await aiofiles.open(filename, mode='wb')
            await f.write(await resp.read())
            await f.close()

async def download_pdf(urls, folder):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
    async with semaphore:
        async with ClientSession(connector=connector, headers=headers) as session:
            tasks = [get_file(url, folder, session) for url in urls]
            result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

urls = ['https://www.example.com/abc.pdf', 'https://www.example2.com/def.pdf']
directory = r'C:\data'
asyncio.run(download_pdf(urls, directory))
```

*How* *to* *download* *files* **efficiently**?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `requests` library you can stream your response into a file:

```
with open(r"/path/to/file", 'w+b') as f:
    for chunk in requests.get(yourURL, stream=True).iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        f.write(chunk)
```